# (MVC pattern) Почему появляется ошибка? Uncaught TypeError: handle is not a function at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, классы, mvc, шаблоны-проектирования, type-error

При наведении на нижний серый прямоугольник, почему появляется такая ошибка? ведь я передаю handle (View.js) в качестве функции. addValue в Model.js функция. Еще пробовал в View.js addEventListener сделать не анонимной функцией, но эффект тот же.

```js
class View{
  constructor(){
    this.bodyElement = document.querySelector('body')
    this.boxElement = this.bodyElement.querySelector('.box')

    this.bindPushArray()
    // eventObserver = new EventObserver()
  }
  bindPushArray(handle){
    this.boxElement.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      handle(e.clientX)
    })
  }
}

class Model {
  constructor() {
    this.arr = []
    this.value = 0
  }

  addValue(newValue){
    this.arr.push(newValue)
    console.log(this.arr);
  }
}

class Controller {
  constructor(model, view) {
    this.model = model
    this.view = view

    this.view.bindPushArray(this.handlePushArray)
  }
  handlePushArray = eCount => {
    this.model.addValue(eCount)
  }
}

const app1 = new Controller(new Model(), new View())
```

```css
#root1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.div-box{
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgb(121, 121, 121);
}

.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgb(199, 199, 199);
}

.input {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root1">
  <div class="div-box"></div>
  <input class="input" type="text" name="inputname" id=""/>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте изменить ваш класс View.

Для создания события передайте фукнцию:

```
class View {
  constructor(){
    this.bodyElement = document.querySelector('body')
    this.boxElement = this.bodyElement.querySelector('.box')

    this.bindPushArray()
    // eventObserver = new EventObserver()
  }
  bindPushArray(handle){
    function move(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      handle(e.clientX)
    }
    this.boxElement.addEventListener('mousemove', move);
  }
}
```

И есть подоздрение, что вызов метода `this.bindPushArray()` в конструкторе не нужен.

Comment: Да, точно, вызов вообще не нужен был =| Спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

#### Описание

Вы создаете метод `bindPushArray` который принимает параметр `handle` и зовет её как функцию.

```js
bindPushArray(handle){
    ...
    handle(e.clientX)
    ...
}
```

В конструкторе зовете метод `bindPushArray` не давая ему параметр, соответственно параметр `handle` получает значение `undefined`.

```js
class View{
    constructor() {
        ....
        this.bindPushArray()
    }
    ...
}
```

А `undefined` нельзя вызвать, так как она не функция. Вот и интерпретатор вам выдает:

> Uncaught TypeError: **handle is not a function** at HTMLDivElement.

Comment: @NaN-Simon `Controller` тут не при чем. Смотрите `View` → `constructor()`. Зовете метод без передачи параметра. И уже не важно куда вы его передавали, конкретно этот вызов не получит параметра и будет действовать так как описал выше

Comment: Да, нашел, спасибо)) не надо было вообще вызывать this.bindPushArray() оказывается, как написали ниже =o